# MICROSERVICES / CONTAINERS | Scale | Event bus | Duplicate messages

Tags: .net, architecture, event-handling, rabbitmq, microservices

Im start moving to micro service architecture 
My cookbook is: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

This is awesome book. But I have questions, and 1 of them is:

Lets say I have 2,3,5,10 instances/containers of Orders micro service

And 3 instances/containers of Payment API

Now When User click Make order- I will send message - New OrderEvent

And Order micro service have to handle this message.....
But..I have 8 instances of this micro services - I each one will handle this message...

(I use rabbit as bus)
So question are:

1. If I do something wrong?
2. If rabbit can protect this problem (I dont think, but maybe...)))
3. If i need to write Complex logic code from protect inside each handle micro service OR I can do magic settings inside bus?

Thank you
(And sorry if this question is duplicate - I didnt find nothing in Internet)
(And sorry for English grammar - I work on this problem)))

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you configure your instance queues and RabbitMQ exchange.

If you use a single queue for all instaces, MQ will ensure that only one consumer will get the message.

Although you could have a queue per instance, then they should be binded in a common exchange. The exchange has an routing pattern, which will ensure that only one, some or all instances queues will receive the sent message.